# How to set a tethered Wi-Fi connection (tethered to another phone via Android personal hotspot) as "metered" connection

Tags: wifi-hotspot, tethering, wifi-tethering

I have a number of apps set to "Download on Wi-Fi Only" on Android. But the moment I tether, the phone considers itself on Wi-Fi, even if the upstream device is a metered 3G/LTE connection.

Under Windows 10, I can declare a given Wi-Fi connection to be "Metered", and thus save data usage.  Is there an equivalent on Android?  Setting the tethered phone to "Data saver" is a partial solution only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a rather hidden feature, that will let you achieve this:

This option is found under Settings > Data usage (Wireless and Networks).

- Tap on the three dots in the top right corner, and press "Mobile Hotspots." (In android 4.3) In later versions of android   the similar option is "Network restrictions" > Metered connections

[image]

Next you'll see  a list of saved wireless networks, and you can check the ones which are mobile hotspots.

[image]

**Edit**

I have included the screenshots for Android 7, since interface and options are different from Android 4.3 above:

[image]

Such that the options are found under Settings > Data usage (Wi-Fi) > Network restrictions > Metered connections

[image]

In this way Android applies the same data restrictions as it does with "Data connections" so no data hogging.

## Update

Other devices like Huawei have this setting hidden but can be also enable using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb):

After setting up adb, follow [this proceedure](https://www.xda-developers.com/wifi-network-metered-huawei-honor/) to set a metered wi-fi network.

> - In a command prompt or terminal, execute the following command: `adb
>     shell`
> - Type the following command into the command prompt or terminal to get a list of all saved WiFi networks: `cmd netpolicy list
>     wifi-networks`
> - You’ll be given a list of saved WiFi networks with a true/false boolean value. True = metered & False = non-metered.
> - So from here, you can enter the following command in a command prompt or terminal to change the setting: `cmd netpolicy set
>     metered-network Wireless true`
>        (In this case the SSID  is “*Wireless*”)
> - You can always revert the setting to false if you want to switch it back to a non-metered network.

Hope this helps

Comment: On Android 7.1, this is in a slightly different place: Settings->Data Usage->(WiFi) Network Restrictions

Comment: @mattm Thanks for putting this up, please feel free to edit if you like.

Comment: Was unable to follow these steps (Huawei p20 lite), comment by @mattm did not help as I cannot even find data usage. -- I did find a data saver somewhere (which might help on an ad hoc basis) but doubt whether it is the same.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I have updated the answer to workarounds for devices with this setting hidden.