# Set wifi connection as metered in Android 5.0

Tags: wi-fi

I'd like to set specific wifi connections as metered, since I do not want e.g. Google Play to update apps via public wifi (limited volume and bandwith, competing with my and - for politeness - other people's laptops).

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 5.0.1, Avast running, no root and no special modifications from my side.

I have tried quite some days to find a native Android way to do that, but failed so far - please prove me wrong! The suggestions I found so far on Android Enthusiasts go mainly into the following directions and did not work (other Android versions, or see below). I'd rather prefer a native android solution, if necessary a 3rd party app would be fine if without rooting.

1. many solutions end at a "3 dot" (⋮) menu somewhere in data usage menu pages - it seems not to exist on my phone/Android version. Found nothing comparable (incl. left menue button next to the start button etc.)
2. restrict background data - I do not want to restrict the app (Google Play) in general, but only a specific network.
3. NetGuard app - same as 2., does not seem to be wifi-specific (and not sure if I should put an app with in app purchases in such a central position)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [How to set a tethered Wi-Fi connection (tethered to another phone via Android personal hotspot) as “metered” connection](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/174090/209414)

Comment: @beeshyams: Fantastic! Although I do not have a "network restrictions" option or sth that sound similar, the next screenshot let me discover that I need to tap "mobile hotspots" instead (not right top, but lower left 'menu' button - not sure why they obfuscate things that way), then get the same (at least similar-looking) list of  networks I can set as (supposedly metered) 'hotspots', resulting in restricted background data usage. Will test and report in case of new aspects. Although very indirect, it helped and I'd accept as answer if you agree and post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metered WiFi connections should be straightforward to set up but Samsung has it buried elsewhere as reported by OP in comments. I don't have the device to illustrate but based on [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/293776/how-to-restrict-background-data-for-metered-wi-fi-networks-on-android/), the steps are :

- Settings → Data usage → WiFi
- Network restrictions should appear here, alongwith the list of Networks. As OP discovered,apparently on some models, instead one has to tap *mobile hotspots* button (accessed from *bottom left* menu button) to reveal the list of Networks.
- Toggle the selected WiFi network to restrict background data (I suppose this is the same as "metered" - please feel free to comment), as explained at the very bottom of the list (in case you find the explanation, you are likely to have managed anyway...)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much difference to the default proceedure for metering wi-fi networks in android.

Here is the proceedure in Samsung J5 Android 5 (which I believe is similar o your device):

Go to Settings → Data Usage → **More** → Restrict networks

> This will show a list of all the Wi-Fi networks the device has ever
>   connected to. Use the switches to enable restrictions on any given
>   network. Once activated, this will prevent apps from using background
>   data on that network, and you’ll also get a warning before any large
>   downloads.

[image: a] [image: b]  [image: c]

[image: d]

Comment: Thanks for the nice illustration by screenshots (+1), but unfortunately I simply do not habe the "more" button (= "3 dots" button in other versions) and "restrict networks" option for unknown reason...